# Make a custom model that will get data from another model laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a model, which is storing foreign key data of various tables. Here is the model details:

```
class InstituteStage extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Branch');
    }

    public function version()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Version');
    }

    public function shift()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Shift');
    }

    public function stage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Stage');
    }

    public function academic_year()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\AcademicYear');
    }
```

}

Right now if i fetch the data, i'm getting those fields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [stage_for] => Teachers
            [branch_id] => 1
            [version_id] => 1
            [shift_id] => 1
            [stage_id] => 1
            [academic_year_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [stage_for] => Students
            [branch_id] => 2
            [version_id] => 2
            [shift_id] => 2
            [stage_id] => 2
            [academic_year_id] => 2
        )
)
```

Now i want the details (such as name) of other tables. The response i'm looking for is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [stage_for] => Teachers
            [institute_stage_name] => "branch_name->version_name->shift_name->stage_name" 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [stage_for] => Students
            [institute_stage_name] => "branch_name->version_name->shift_name->stage_name" 
        )
)
```

I can get datas using eager loading and concat them in frontend. But i want to use a custom model which will return this details. Is it possible to get this structure!

i made another static method in my model and getting all the data:

```
public static function student_institute_stage_data()
{
    return static::where([
        ['stage_for', 'Students'],
        ['status', 'active']
    ])
    ->with(['branch', 'version', 'shift', 'stage'])
    ->get();
}
```

then in my controller:

```
$instituteStage = InstituteStage::student_institute_stage_data();
```

after that in my blade, im doing this ->

```
@foreach ($instituteStage as $stage)
    <option value="{{ $stage->id }}" {{ old('institute_stage_id') === $stage->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $stage->branch->name . "->" . $stage->version->name . "->" . $stage->shift->name . "->" . $stage->stage->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller, what you tried?

Comment: Right now i'm doing the long way, getting all data separately using eager load and then into the blade, i'm concating them where i needed.

Comment: You need to do that in your controller, so if you share minimal portion of code it will be helpful for others to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an accessor in your `InstituteStage` Model:

```php
public funcion getInstituteStageNameAttribute($value)
{
    return sprintf(
        '%s->%s->%s->%s',
        $this->branch->name,
        $this->version->name,
        $this->shift->name,
        $this->stage->name
    );
}
```

In this way, when you try to access the `institute_stage_name` property on a Institute State model, the function above gets executed.

Then in your controller you can simply do:

```php
$stages = InstituteStage::where([
    ['stage_for', 'Student'],
    ['status', 'active']
])
->with('branch', 'version', 'shift', 'stage')
->get();
```

And finally in your blade view:

```html
@foreach ($stages as $stage)
    <option value="{{ $stage->id }}" {{ old('institute_stage_id') === $stage->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $stage->institute_stage_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

You can dig deeper into some useful methods like accessors in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

#### Update

If you further want to move your query outside your controller I would personally use local and dynamic scopes in the model (documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)).

To get the maximum flexibility I would separate the two where conditions you need in two local scopes:

```php
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'active');
}

public function scopeFor($query, $type)
{
    return $query->with('branch', 'version', 'shift', 'stage')
        ->where('stage_for', $type);
}
```

You could then use these two methods with the query builder syntax like this:

```php
$stages = InstituteStage::for('Student')->active()->get();
```

If you always need for active stages when you use the `for` local scope you have defined, then you can move the `->active()` method call inside the `scopeFor` method:

```php
public function scopeFor($query, $type)
{
    return $query->with('branch', 'version', 'shift', 'stage')
        ->where('stage_for', $type)
        ->active();
}
```

And the query would become:

```php
$stages = InstituteStage::for('Student')->get();
```

The power of useing query scopes is that they doesn't stop you from further apply any query builder method before/after them so you have a common method to apply basic filtering in a simpler way, then you can further customize (if needed) the query with additional wheres, joins, etc, and finally get the result.

#### Update: Clarification on Accessor

> Can you explain how we are getting the concated name by calling 'institute_stage_name' as it is not showing in the array?

That's how the accessors works: you can define a method called `getYourPropNameAttribute($value)` that will be called automatically by laravel when you try to access its relative property, in this case: `$model->your_prop_name` (note the studly/pascal casing of the property name in the accessor's function name).

Quote from the documentation:

> To define an accessor, create a `getFooAttribute` method on your model where `Foo` is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.

**How does it work *code-wise***
When you access a property on one of your models (that all extends laravel's model class) the following functions will be executed:

- The `__get` magic method <sup>([source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1521))</sup> will be executed and will call the `getAttribute` function <sup>([source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L308))</sup>
- The `getAttribute` will call `hasGetMutator` ([source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L436)) to check if a method called `get + ThePropYouAreAccessingName + Attribute` exists in your model class
- If the property you are accessing has an accessor method OR is an attribute of the model then retrive its value with the `getAttributeValue` call (defined a few lines below `getAttribute`.
- If mutator exists, then it is called by the framework and its value returned to the place where you accessed the property in the first place.

Comment: Thank you..This is almost what i was looking for.. I already read about mutation. But couldn't figured it out. But is it possible to filter it more. I mean, i am looking for a method like this -----> InstituteStage::institute_stage_name() . And which will return all rows with those name. all those condition will be into that methods too..

Comment: But can you explain how we are getting the concated name by calling 'institute_stage_name' as it is not showing in the array. I didn't get this part

Comment: I have updated once again to include more details, please let me know if your doubts has been solved